# Retrieving data from files using Axios, html files return 404 error but other file types work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm using Axios in Vue.js to retrieve data from files. I have files on my server, and I just want to retrieve their content so I can display it.

It's working with almost any file type (txt, css, js...) I can retrieve their content with no problem. But when the file is a .html, I get a 404 error ("Error: Request failed with status code 404"). I'm sure the file is there; in fact, if I rename it to a .txt, axios has no trouble finding it.

Here's my code... Nothing out of the ordinary:

```
axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: '/src/library/test.html'
      })
        .then((result) => {
          this.htmlContent = result.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
```

It's my first time using Axios, so I'm having trouble seing what I'm missing. Any idea?

Comment: We've no way of knowing why your server can't find files you think are at the URLs you are asking for.

Comment: have you checked the url in the browser that the file is accessible from browser?